# KineticJS. draw image with onClick event

Tags: kineticjs

I'm trying to draw image into KineticJS canvas with onClick event, but it doesn't work.
Error like this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined
imageObj.onload
How to make stage & layer vars visible for drawImage function? Hope smb can help me cause I've already haven't ideas to do this

```
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",  // div with id 'container'
        width: 578,
        height: 500,                
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();        

    function drawImage(src) {       
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 100,
                y: 110,
                image: imageObj,
                draggable: true,
            });

            layer.add(image);

            stage.add(layer);
        };

        imageObj.src = src;
    }
```

...
img src="testImage.jpg" onclick="drawImage(this.src);"

Answer (score 0):

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

is this statement called before your event onclick ?

What if you do this

```
Img src="testImage.jpg" onclick="var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();  drawImage(this.src);"
```